# create a new variable in each iteration

Tags: r, loops, variables

I want to create a new variable when i´m running a loop.
For example, in a for loop from 1 to 10, create the variable t1, t2, t3 and so on.

```
for i in 1:10{
              Ti=i
                   }
```

How can i do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The code is written in R.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and show what you are trying to achieve, i.e. expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you would do this, but there is a way too do this. There's a function in R called `assign`. You can write

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  assign(paste0("T", i), i, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
# Check that we have those variables
ls()
#> [1] "i"   "T1"  "T10" "T2"  "T3"  "T4"  "T5"  "T6"  "T7"  "T8"  "T9"
```

The first argument to `assign` is the name of the variable. The second is the value to be assigned to the variable. The third is the environment in which the variable shall live. Here I put the variable into the global environment.

That said, a better way to approach this kind of problem is to use the `apply` family of functions, which generates a vector that stores the output of each iteration of the loop, or to first start a vector, and then fill in the vector; this way the values you are generating in the for loop are kept in the same place and are easier to organize and compute with. R is very vectorized.

Edit: Another piece of advise: global assignment is often considered bad, because it may add cryptic dependencies, making code hard to debug when something goes wrong.

Comment: If you use `ls.str()` you can also check quickly that the variables contain what you expect them to.